# How is the array "ggg" initialized and what is .split()?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.System.*;

public class herons {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
  Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("herons.dat"));
  int times = file.nextInt();
  //System.out.println(times);
  for(int i =0;i<times;i++) {

   String mss = file.next();
   //char[] hfh = mss.toCharArray();
   String ggg[] = mss.split(",");
   //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ggg));

   //char[] gegg = ggg.toCharArray();
   Scanner sc = new Scanner (ggg[0]);
   Scanner sc1 = new Scanner (ggg[1]);
   Scanner sc2 = new Scanner (ggg[2]);



   double a=sc.nextDouble();
   double b=sc1.nextDouble();
   double c=sc2.nextDouble();


   double s = (a+b+c)/(2.0);

   double sq = (s)*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c);

   double area = Math.sqrt(sq);


   System.out.printf("%.3f",area); System.out.println("");
  }
 }
}
```

Hi I am a student taking Java and I was wondering if someone could explain where the array "ggg" is initialized and what .split() is used for? The inputs are three numbers separated by commas. 
Thank you!

Comment: Where? "`String ggg[] = mss.split(",");`". What is `split` for? [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-).

Comment: You don't need to create a `Scanner` to convert a `String` to a `double`. `double a = Double.parseDouble(ggg[0]);` is sufficient.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know much about java, could you explain what `double.parseDouble(ggg[0])` actually does? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Array is initialized right here:

```
String ggg[] = mss.split(",");
```

Split will take string `mss` and *split* it into array of sub-strings using provided text/regex - in your case it's ",".

Example:

```
String mss = "a,b,cc,ddd";
String[] split = mss.split(",");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
// output: [a, b, cc, ddd]
```

Link to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))